# Proving reed solomon codes are linear

Tags: discrete-mathematics, polynomials, proof-writing, coding-theory

I'm supposed to prove that any two reed solomon codes added together produce a reed solomon code.

We're supposed to prove this over the coefficient encoding, where the code word is the evaluation of some polynomial $P(x)$ at ${0,1,...,m−1}$. Assume we are working on GF(p) for large enough p.

I created two polynomials to represent the reed-solomon codes:
$$P_{0}(x) = c_{n-1}x^{n-1} +...+ c_{1}x + c_{0}$$ message is $(c_{n-1},...c_{0})$
$$P_{1}(x) = d_{n-1}x^{n-1} +...+ d_{1}x + d_{0}$$ message is $(d_{n-1},...d_{0})$

Their sum is $$P(x) = (d_{n-1}+c_{n-1}) x^{n-1} +...+ (d_{1} + c_{1}) x + (d_{0} + c_{0})$$ message is $(d_{n-1}+c_{n-1},...,d_{0} + c_{0})$

I know I need to prove that

- $P(i) = R(i)$ where $R(i)$ is the received code for at least $n+k$ points, where k is the errors
- $P(x)$ is a unique degree-$(n-1)$ polynomial with at least $n+k$ received points

But I'm not sure how to do so. I'd appreciate some hints! I was considering induction

EDIT - still kinda stuck on this. Is it enough to prove that the polynomial is n-1 degree ?

Comment: To give a helpful answer I need to know what is your definition of a Reed-Solomon code. There are several equivalent ways of defining them. Also, there seems to be some confusion with terminology (that may actually preventinig your progress). A single polynomial is a *word* (or a *codeword*) of an RS-code. The RS-code  itself is a *collection* of polynomials. Being *linear* is a property of that collection.

Comment: Furthermore, in proving the claim in the title you don't need to discuss *errors* at all. It is all about which polynomials belong to the set (of valid codewords).

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen we were taught that a valid Reed-Solomon code message is one of the form (p(0), p(1), ..., p(m-1)) where p(x) is a polynomial of degree n-1. the message of length m makes up the coefficients in the polynomial, and the codeword is the message plus extra data points to account for error/corruption. The codeword  is the evaluation of p(x) at {0,1,...,m−1}.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The notation that the OP's instructor is using is *very* non-standard; most coding people use $n$ for the number of symbols in each *codeword* (a codeword is a *vector* in an $n$-dimensional space) and $k$ for the number of *information* symbols (the data we wish to transmit).

Be that as it may, and sticking with the OP's notation, the *information symbols*
$c_0, c_1, \ldots, c_{n-1}$ (these are elements of GF$(p)$) that the transmitter wish to convey to the receiver are *encoded* using a Reed-Solomon code which operates follows. The information symbols are treated as the coefficients of a polynomial $P(x) = c_0 + c_1x + \cdots + c_{n-1}x^{n-1}$ and **what is transmitted is the $m$-vector** $\big(P(0), P(1), \ldots, P(m-1)\big)$. **What is absolutely crucial is the requirement that** $n \leq m$, that is, there are at least as many transmitted symbols as the number of information symbols that we wish to convey to the receiver (and preferably several more).  If we like, we can represent $\big(P(0), P(1), \ldots, P(m-1)\big)$ as another polynomial
$$Q(z) = P(0) + P(1)z + \cdots + P(m-1)z^{m-1}$$
and think of the *encoding process* as mapping the *information polynomial* $P(x)$ to the *codeword polynomial* $Q(z)$.  With this as background,

> The OP is asked to prove that the sum of any two *codeword polynomials* is a *codeword polynomial*, that is, if $Q(z)$ and $Q^\prime(z)$ are two *codeword polynomials* (corresponding to *information polynomials* $P(x)$ and $P^\prime(x)$) respectively,)
> then $Q(z)+Q^\prime(z)$ is *also* a *codeword polynomial*, that is, there exists some *information polynomial* $R(x)$ (remember it must have degree $n-1$ or less) such that $Q(z)+Q^\prime(z)$ is the image of $R(x)$:

$$ P(x) \mapsto Q(z), \quad P^\prime(x) \mapsto Q^\prime(z), \implies \exists R(x)
\mapsto Q(z)+Q^\prime(z) $$
It seems to me that $R(x) = P(x)+P^\prime(x)$ fits the bill, but the OP's mmv.

Answer (score 1):

By definition a Reed-Solomon polynomial is a multiple of the generator, and the sum of two multiples is a multiple.

Comment: whats a generator? is that just the polynomial

Comment: @MelanieSanders: do you ignore what the generator is in Reed-Solomon ?

Comment: The particular Reed-Solomon code that the OP is using is _not_ a cyclic code and doesn't have a generator polynomial in the usual sense. In fact, the formulation the OP is using is the one in the original 1960 paper by Reed and Solomon; the connection to cyclic codes (for specific Reed-Solomon codes) was developed later.

Comment: @DilipSarwate: bad luck :-(